# Term for original use or first intention

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing about a cultural artifact that is now used as an aesthetic object in a museum but, prior to this ethnographic view, was used as a ceremonial object. I'm looking for a term that refers to this initial use. (I'd use it for a section heading.)

To clarify from the comments, I am looking for a single, detached term/noun particularly because "original purpose/use" can connote that the object has lost that first intent. In my case, the object was really just stolen and could still be used for its original intent if someone were returned to its creators.

In a sentence: "While the mask today is appreciated for its aesthetic qualities, its [original usage or first intention] was as a ceremonial totem."

Comment: Why does "original usage" not work? Would **original purpose** fit better?

Comment: If you use *its purpose was*, it would make things clear.

Comment: Its _creation_ was strictly as a ceremonial totem for ritual, not for decor.

Comment: *... it was originally a ceremonial totem.*

Comment: Insofar as "design" implies intended form, function, uses, and users, you might consider some variant like "originally designed as." Though were this mine, I'd be trying to work "appreciated" into the second clause for parallelism. One possibility: While the mask today is appreciated for its aesthetic qualities, its intended users would have appreciated its role as a ceremonial totem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the term ***[genesis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/genesis):***

> - the origin or coming into being of something. (M-W)
>
>   - *Moscow would move beyond its genesis as a frontier village to develop into a progressive community with contacts throughout the nation and the world.* From ([Moscow: Living and Learning on the Palouse](https://books.google.it/books?id=_PptM9yqWEcC&pg=PT176&dq=%22its%20genesis%20as%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAuOv3g7HSAhWDvxQKHWvWAEsQ6AEILTAE#v=onepage&q=%22its%20genesis%20as%22&f=false))

- "While the mask today is appreciated for its aesthetic qualities, its genesis was as a ceremonial totem."